# glob qualifier to select files under version control

Tags: svn, zsh

Imagine a directory `/path/to/trunk` which is under version control with svn. While the directory and some of its files are under version control, others are not.

> **Question:** How can I create a glob which selects the files which are under version control and is fast?

**workaround:** Instead of using a glob, make use of `svn ls` and use an array

```
array=( "${(@f)$(svn ls -R /path/to/trunk)}" )
```

I'm not a big fan of this solution because you could run filenames with annoying characters and you should [never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

**possible solution:** make use of a function and the execute glob-qualifier:

```
$ undersvn() { svn ls --depth empty "$REPLY" >/dev/null 2>&1 }
array=( /path/to/trunk/**/*(+undersvn) )
```

This method is excellent and works fine. However, on large trees with a lot of files, this becomes slow as it executes `svn ls` for every single file it finds.

> Is there a way to do this faster/better?

Comment: You probably already realize this, but it's worth stating explicitly: having a glob that recognizes files under source control would require a level of Subversion integration that `zsh` doesn't have.

Comment: Apparently svn's `ls` command isn't designed for safe machine consumption. Compare this to `git-ls-files`, which has a `-z` flag to turn on NUL-delimiting. Maybe you need to write your own svn "extension" to achieve this; not having much experience with svn, I don't know how extensible it is, but a cursory search seems to say it's not as extensible as say git or hg, unfortunately.